# How to we can maintain two API versions in Magento 2 in case of particular change request

Tags: rest, magento, graphql, magento2.4

I wants to make few changes in Magento 2 core API by extending this and wants to run both the API (old one and new with changes). Please suggest the standard way out.

Answer (score 0):

7 Easy steps to extend magento2 REST API

Step 1: Create a Separate module for extending magento2 REST API

Step 2: Create di.xml into

> app/code/Ipragmatech/Restfulapi/etc/

Step 3: Create webapi.xml into

> app/code/Ipragmatech/Restfulapi/etc/

Step 4: Create OrderInterface.php into

> app/code/Ipragmatech/Restfulapi/Api/

Step 5: Create Order.php into

> app/code/Ipragmatech/Restfulapi/Model/

Step 6: Create the di.xml file into

> app/code/Ipragmatech/Restfulapi/etc/webapi_rest/

Step 7: Check the myorder API on postman
Detailed instructions can be found [here](https://pragmaapps.com/extend-magento2-rest-api-easy-steps/).

Comment: Let suppose, I make any change using event observer or plugin in core functionality then it will be reflect for both the API but here I wants make these separate.